# Replace td by image depending on value

Tags: javascript, php, html, smarty

I'm working on a project using Smarty.
I want to display the results of my array on my web page, and replace the '1' results by an image, and '0' results by an another.
I can so far get my results like i want i just need to do this replacement and i don't really know if it's possible and if it is, how would i manage to do it.
Here's a part of my php code:

```
for ($c=0; $c<count($aLPO); $c++){
$aPG['P_I'] = $aLPO[$c]['P_I'];
$aPG['P_L'] = $aLPO[$c]['P_L']; 
$sGA = $aLPO[$c]['P_G_A'];
for ($i=0; $i<count($aGId); $i++){
        if (strpos($sGA , $aGId[$i]) !== false){
            $sGId = $aGId[$i]; 
            $aPG[$aG[$sGId ]] = '1';
        }
        else{
            $sGId = $aGId[$i];
            $aPG[$aG[$sGId ]] = '0';
        }   
}
array_push($aPO, $aPG);
unset($aPG);
```

}

```
$smarty->assign("aLPO", $aPO);
```

And a part of my .tpl code (html/smarty)

```
...
<div id="display_table_Produit_Gammes">
        <table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 class="tbl_datas" id="table_Produit" >
        {if $iNbProduitsOptions == 0}
            <thead>
                <tr><th></th></tr>
            </thead>
        {else}
            <thead>             
                <tr>
                    <th width='8%'>ID</th>
                    <th width='10%'>P_L</th>
                    {foreach from=$aLG item=g name=lst}
                        <th>{$g.G_L} ({$g.G_I})</th>
                    {/foreach}
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                    {foreach from=$aLPO item=p name=lst}
                        <tr>
                        {foreach from=$p item=pval}                        
                                <td>{$pval}</td>                            
                        {/foreach}
                        </tr>
                    {/foreach}
            </tbody>    
            {/if}
        </table>
</div>
```

The results i need to change are in my  tag, since they are dynamically charged i'm a bit confused on the way to deal with.

Thanks in advance for your help and feel free to ask me for some more informations if you need (since i'm not english it can be hard to understand the purpose of the topic i hope it's clear enough)

Comment: Question unclear. Why don't you show it directly, putting an if condition. if pval = 0 <img src='image1.jpg'> else <img src='image2.jpg'>. If you want to do it with javascript make it classes. <td class="replaceable{{$pval}}"></td> and then replace all td's which have the classes replaceable0 or replaceable1

Comment: I don't know, looking better i would say ^^ but yes your solution is working quite nicely so i'll do with it.
I'm still not used with Smarty so .. , anyway thanks a lot for your help see ya!

Answer (score 1):

Here is better explained answer:
In smarty you can use:

```
{if $pval eq '0'}
    <img src="image0.jpg">
{else}
    <img src="image0.jpg">
{/if}
```

If using javascript to do this you can write:

```
{foreach from=$p item=pval}                        
    <td class="replace_this_{$pval}"></td>                            
{/foreach}
```

in order to add a class to the td and then in javascript:

```
// select elements:
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("replace_this_0");
// replace the <td></td> with <td><img src="image0.jpg"></td>
for(var i= 0; i< elems.length; ++i)
{
  elems[i].innerHTML = "<img src='image0.jpg'>";
}
```

And the same for the second image. Hope this helps.